# How do you use a railcard on TFL if you pay by phone or debit/credit card?

Tags: uk, trains, london, tfl, tube

[TFL allows you to add a National Railcard to an Oyster card](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/free-and-discounted-travel/national-railcard-discount). However, most people use a bank card either with the physical card or via an NFC payment system.

Is there any way to add an existing railcard to a debit card or credit card or Google Wallet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot.

As of November 2022, [contactless (bank cards or NFC devices)](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares/how-to-pay-and-where-to-buy-tickets-and-oyster/pay-as-you-go/contactless-and-mobile-pay-as-you-go) support only extends to a "pay as you go" model for a single adult fare with daily and weekly cap.

For railcard discounts, student/young persons discounts, travelcards, season tickets, etc., a registered Oyster card is required.